# Deploying a sequelize-cli app to heroku DATABASE_URL issue

Tags: heroku, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm using sequelize migrations. Here is my config.js:

```js
require('dotenv').config()

module.exports = {
  development: {
    database: process.env.DEV_DATABASE,
    host: process.env.DEV_HOST,
    dialect: 'postgres'
  },
  test: {
    database: process.env.TEST_DATABASE,
    host: process.env.TEST_HOST,
    dialect: 'postgres'
  },
  production: {
    database: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    dialect: 'postgres'
  },
}
```

When I deploy to heroku and run:

```sh
heroku run npx sequelize-cli db:migrate
```

I get the error:

```sh
Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
Using environment "production".

ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
```

I have tried changing my config to `use_env_variable: DATABASE_URL` and I get `Error reading "config/config.js". Error: ReferenceError: DATABASE_URL is not defined`

If I `console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL)` I get something like:

```
postgres://bczwqcbnwftivi:80bbc89546c0953e0ffd221a950cac249d25d4ef1812127054af7c2f504b2c39@ec2-54-225-205-79.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d8gsvl0n8qilcs
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked:

```js
{
    "development": {
        "database": "products_api_development",
        "dialect": "postgres"
    },
    "test": {
        "database": "products_api_test",
        "dialect": "postgres"
    },
    "production": {
        "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL",
        "dialect": "postgres",
        "dialectOptions": {
            "ssl": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah it is correct if we want to use database url in production we need to add the key of env variable into here

 "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL",

note DATABASE_URL key is the name you save database name within .evn file

Answer (score -1):

Here's further [documentation for configuring the sequelize config](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/blob/main/docs/README.md) file.

More info on setting up [environment variables on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars):

You can set up environment variables at `https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/[your-app-name]/settings`. In the case of node.js those variables will then be available in your app using `process.env.[variable-name]`.

[image: Settings]